# Why to use bash in executing script?

Tags: bash, scripts, sudo, executable, sh

In a former question, I was suggested to execute:

```
sudo bash start-dfs.sh
```

why not

```
sudo start-dfs.sh
```

? I mean, what difference does `bash` makes?

Comment: the last one can be used if `start-dfs.sh` is executable *and* starts with a shebang.

Comment: @JacobVlijm you should convert that to an answer you can run sudo .. if shebang and executable, otherwise sudo bash ...

Comment: @JacobVlijm is right, what is a shebang? `./` ?

Comment: @gsamaras answer will be posted in a minute :) working on it.

Comment: @gsamaras my edit crossed yours, sorry, didn't notice. good suggestion, I will edit it in :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script in *any* (interpreted) language, like `bash` or `python`, needs to be "interpreted" by the interpreter of the corresponding language.

On Linux, this can be done in different ways:

1. The interpreter is "asked" to run the script by including the language in the command to run the script:

   ```
   <language> <script>
   ```

   or in your example:

   ```
   sudo bash start-dfs.sh
   ```
2. The script is *executable*, and has the permission to "ask" the interpreter itself to run the code inside the script. from your example:

   ```
   sudo start-dfs.sh
   ```

   In this case, the script *must* start with the *shebang*, else there is no information what interpreter to call, like:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   ```

   or:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   ```

#### Notes

- In case the first option is used, the language information in the command *always* overrules a possible shebang, no matter if the script is executble or not.
- The extension on a script (`.sh`, `.py` etc) makes clear what type of script it is, but plays *no role whatsoever* in the execution of a script, unlike in windows.